# Your project is not using the default configuration for build and test

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am running the command 'ng add @angular/material' in the angular cli. and these problem appears. I am using Angular 6 for the MEAN Stack Application.

Error message:
Installing packages for tooling via npm. 
Your project is not using the default configuration for build and test. The Angular Material schematics can only be used with the default configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had just run into it myself and got the solution from here https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11438

Apparently there is an invalid key in `angular.json` file where `targets` needs to be renamed to `architect`

`{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
------>"architect": { <--------- originally targets
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/project-name",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
...`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. My project used not default builder, so I encountered the same error.
I created the default project using  `ng new my-app` and install angular-material there.
 Then I compared the difference between default `angular.json` and my `angular.json` and found out that my file does not contain path for angular-material library in `styles` options. I copied them manually like this and everything worked well!

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets",
    "src/favicon.ico"
  ],
  "styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
--> "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css", <-- I added this line
    "node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css",
    "node_modules/@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/css/okta-sign-in.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": []
},
```